# APA7 style with publisher and address

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, apa7

I'm using biblatex with biber and "apa" style, which is appearently APA7.

In this style - using an book entry in the .bib file - the publisher and the address is not printed in the bibliography.

[image: Bibliography with apa style]

How can i achieve to print the full address of the publisher as in APA6 and the following example (note: publisher was removed using \DeclareSourcemap)
[image]

I'm looking forward to your help.

Comment: page 2 of the biblatex-apa documentation mentions the biblatex-apa6 package https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references `@book` references should show the `publisher`, but not the `location`/`address` field in APA7 style.

This is exactly what happens if you use an up-to-date version of `biblatex-apa`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, A. (1972). A theory on brontosauruses. Monthy & Co.]

---

If you want 6th edition APA style, where both `publisher` and `location` are shown, you should load `biblatex-apa6`'s `style=apa6,`

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa6]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, A. (1972). A theory on brontosauruses. London: Monthy & Co.]

---

If you absolutely need `biblatex-apa`'s 7th-edition APA style to show the location (which is *not* APA compliant), you can try to patch the drivers like this

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\usebibmacro{location+publisher}}
  {}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, A. (1972). A theory on brontosauruses. London, Monthy & Co.]